# Android Full Width CardView

Tags: android

Here is the output I am getting :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/10UbN.png (I dont have enough credits to post image )

Here is the XML Code I am using :-

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/myCardView"
                                    cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                                    cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                                    cardview:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:contentDescription="Event Image"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Event Title"
                android:textColor="#222"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:gravity="top"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Short Description of Event"
                android:textColor="#222"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:id="@+id/short_desc"
                android:padding="8dp"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1000"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I want to get a full width Card View which I am not able to achieve.
Help ! Thanks :)

Comment: can you show you recycler xml or activity xml where you set your card view.  there may be padding..  well cardview:cardUseCompatPadding do Add padding in API v21+ as well to have the same measurements with previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

           ....

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: are you sure you set width to `match_parent`? and show root layout.

Comment: Do you want the Java Implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

What in your `onCreateViewHolder`?  
Try inflating your card this way

```
final View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.item_preview, parent, false);
```